# embed swf in htmlloader with captive runtime

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I have a file "test.swf" sitting in the same directory as the air app, and I have the following actionscript...

```
var htmlLoader:HTMLLoader = HTMLLoader.createRootWindow(true, options,false, new Rectangle(0,0,1024, 768));
htmlLoader.loadString(***STRING****);
```

Where ***STRING*** is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="1024" height="768"> 
        <param name="movie" value="app:/test.swf" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea why test.swf doesn't display?!

I also tried `<param name="movie" value="test.swf" />` and `<param name="movie" value="/test.swf" />`

**NOTE:** `<param name="movie" value="http://location.on.web/test.swf" />` does work, but I need this specifically for local playback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, HTML loaded using the [loadString()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html#loadString%28%29) method is not placed in a sandbox for local storage access.  To enable it you need to set the [placeLoadStringContentInApplicationSandbox property](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html#placeLoadStringContentInApplicationSandbox) first:

```
htmlLoader.placeLoadStringContentInApplicationSandbox = true;
```

<sub>And yes, I do think that is the longest property name in the entire AS3 library.</sub>

Comment: Works! Though I also had to put the SWF in the AIR package resources